# JavaScript to delay execution of functions after page is loaded

Tags: javascript

I wrote this javascript to make an animation. It is working fine in the home page. I wrote a alert message in the last.

If I go other then home page, this alert message has to come, but I am getting alert message, if I remove the function, alert message working on all pages, any thing wrong in my code?

```
window.onload = function(){

    var yellows = document.getElementById('magazine-brief').getElementsByTagName('h2');
    var signUp = document.getElementById('signup-link');

        if (yellows != 'undefined' && signUp != undefined){
            function animeYellowBar(num){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    yellows[num].style.left = "0";
                    if(num == yellows.length-1){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            signUp.style.webkitTransform = "scale(1)";
                        },num*250);
                    }

                }, num * 500);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < yellows.length; i++){
                animeYellowBar(i);
            }
        }

    alert('hi');

}
```

Comment: Your Javascript is probably throwing an error on the other pages, Look in Firebug

Comment: i am work with comodo editor, just i am writing there and pasting to here, i know that this is wrong. and i tried using code element even though i can't make proper formating, can you help me with simple way?

Comment: create a http://jsfiddle.net/ for your code

Comment: yes, it say : var yellows = document.getElementById(...-brief').getElementsByTagName('h2');  then how to solve it?

Comment: It's not really "wrong", but defining a function in an "if" statement block like that is pretty unorthodox, and it's not necessary.

Comment: Also, I'm not 100% sure but I think that a "-" character in element "id" values may make IE unhappy.

Comment: You've posted pretty much the same question (minus the cruft) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119082/onload-function-issue) - you could've easily continued the discussion on this page and provided your newer observations as edits. You did not clarify that your second page does not have the `magazine-brief` element - had you mentioned that, the problem would've been trivial to solve.

Answer (score 2):

> - **DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/enaqu5/2

```
var yellows,signUp;
window.onload = function() {
    yellows = document.getElementById('magazine-brief').getElementsByTagName('h2');
    signUp = document.getElementById('signup-link');
    if (yellows !== undefined && signUp !== undefined) {
        for (var i = 0; i < yellows.length; i++) {
            animeYellowBar(i);
        }
    }
  alert('hi')
}
function animeYellowBar(num) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        yellows[num].style.left = "0";
        if (num == yellows.length - 1) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                signUp.style.webkitTransform = "scale(1)";
            },
            num * 250);
        }
    },
    num * 500);
}
```

> - **DEMO 2:** http://jsbin.com/utixi4 (*just for sake*)

```
$(function() {
    $("#magazine-brief h2").each(function(i,item) {
          $(this).delay(i+'00').animate({'marginLeft': 0 }, 500 ,function(){
           if ( i === ( $('#magazine-brief h2').length - 1 ) )
             $('#signup-link')[0].style.webkitTransform = "rotate(-2deg)";
          });
    });
});
```

Comment: @3gwebtrain: see the updated version. i missed to declare the global. try it now it work.

Comment: till this is not work. firebug show the error on second page like this:

Comment: @3gwebtrain: i have personally tested it in FF and it work fine.

Comment: @aSeptik:  He's pasting this into HIS html, which is obviously worse than his javascript was.  Btw... Don't appreciate the ninja after I answered with corrected JS and you fix your initial broken js by hijacking mine.

Comment: i have not hijacked your code, maybe i can't edit my own post? i have just switched from declaring two times the same vars to global scope that's all, it's just a matter of think quickly, write quickly, miss something.. but you know this.

Answer (score 1):

For starters you are not clearing your SetTimeout and what are you truly after here?  You have 2 anonymous methods that one triggers after half a second and the other triggers a quarter of a second later.

So this is just 2 delayed function calls with horribly broken syntax.

**Edited** Two possibilities, one fixes your current code... the latter shows you how to do it using JQuery which I would recomend:

```
var yellows, signUp;

window.onload = function(){
    yellows = document.getElementById('magazine-brief');
    if(yellows != null){
        yellows = yellows.getElementsByTagName('h2');
    }else{
        yellows = null;
    }
    signUp = document.getElementById('signup-link');

    if (yellows != null && signUp != null && yellows.length > 0)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < yellows.length; i++)
        {
            animeYellowBar(i);
        }
    }
    alert('hi');
}

function animeYellowBar(num)
{
    setTimeout(function(){
        yellows[num].style.left = "0";
        if(num == yellows.length-1){
            setTimeout(function(){
                signUp.style.webkitTransform = "scale(1)";
            },num*250);
        }
    }, num * 500);
}
```

The below approach is a SUMMARY of how to use JQuery, if you want to use JQuery I'll actually test it out:

```
//Or using JQuery
//Onload equivelent
$(function(){
    var     iterCount = 0,
        maxIter = $("#magazine-brief").filter("h2").length;
    $("#magazine-brief").filter("h2").each(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(this).css({left: 0});
            if(iterCount == (maxIter-1))
            {
                setTimeout(function(){  
                    signUp.style.webkitTransform = "scale(1)";
                    },iterCount*250);
            }
        }, iterCount++ * num );
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried the first methos, firebug through an error like : 1first line : document.getElementById("magazine-brief") is null, second line : yellows = document.getElementById(...-brief').getElementsByTagName('h2');

Comment: @3gwebtrain:  Seriously?  It means that your getElementById returned null so the further search failed.  So... I've updated my solution to handle that... make sure unless your going to include JQuery to NOT include anything after the //Or using JQuery!!!!

Comment: @VulgarBinary: also just if you want learn the way of ninja your jquery code should look like this: http://jsbin.com/utixi4  ;)

Comment: @aSeptik: I admit defeat, coding jQuery to a solution (that the asker won't even use) while taking a 3 minute breather at work doesn't leave time to write the actual example and refine.  ;-)  Was just a off the cuff example.  Props.  Yours is better.

Comment: @VulgarBinary: hey bro, i know that, it's the same for me! ;) this is why i posted that code! btw... +1 for the time you spent on writing your code. ;)

Comment: @aSeptik:  Bumped you a while ago :-P  Now watch the asker abandon... yippie!

Comment: @aSeptik - Yep... ofc the asker abandoned... this is why I hate stack.  No clean-up crew.