# onload function issue

Tags: javascript

I use this javascript on the home page, and that page contain h2 tags within an element magazine-brief, the alert is working well. If I go to any other page which does not have an element magazine-brief the alert box does not work. How can i solve this problem. my code is :

```
window.onload = function(){
    var yellows = document.getElementById('magazine-brief').getElementsByTagName('h2');
    alert('hi');
}
```

Comment: Do you want to add an `id` to your `<h2>` container?

Comment: No, my alert box has to work across the site, whether the container got h2 element or not

Comment: I feel you should've edited and continued your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118458/is-there-anything-wrong-in-my-javascript) rather than ditch all those people who tried to help you there. You could've easily trimmed down the code on that page to help clarify the question.

Comment: what you say is correct, but i unable to explain very detail with big codes, that's why i trimed and asking. if this is not good, i am sorry. to take help only i do like this. not to pain any one. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your script is failing on the first call to .getElementById and won't execute any further. I suggest you check first to see if the element even exists:

```
var brief = document.getElementById('magazine-brief');
if (brief !== undefined) { // do the rest }
```

Comment: i used this not work window.onload = function(){

   var brief = document.getElementById('magazine-brief');
    if (brief !== undefined) {
        var mybrief = document.getElementById('magazine-brief').getElementsByTagName('h2');
 
    }

   alert('hi');

}
dosn't work. through error : document.getElementById("magazine-brief") is null

Answer (score 0):

If the page doesn't have an element with the id 'magazine-brief', then the `getElementsByTagName` will throw an error, because it's trying to call a method on null. You should get the element, then check it.

Rui J beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

If the said page does not have any elements with the ID, "magazine-brief", then the code will fail at that point and not go to the next line of code.

This is why alerts are a useful way to tell if code has failed. The code you posted will indicate whether or not a page has and element names "magazine-id".